# Google maps api not loading

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am experimenting with Google maps API. I do not have an API key, but as far as I'm aware you do not need a key for v3.
However the map is not rendering on the page and I am not sure what the issue is.
 here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place searches</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
var map;
var infowindow;

function initMap() {
  var pyrmont = {lat: -33.867, lng: 151.195};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
  });

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 500,
    types: ['store']
  }, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you getting any errors on the developer tools console?

Comment: you don't seem to be calling `initMap` at all - the docmentation for google maps  shows `&callback=initMap` as part of the script tag src

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false
```

can you use this;

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&callback=initMap
```